# Как из фото сделать макет для activity?

Tags: android, activity

Есть картинка, как будет выглядеть стартовое окно android приложения. Вопрос - можно ли залить эту картинку и сделать из нее макет для activity ? (Извиняюсь, если плохо сформулировал вопрос)

Comment: Вы имеете ввиду Splash screen c картинкой типа лого? Или макет с формами и кнопками?

Comment: скорее макет, на котором есть 2 EditText и 2 кнопки

Comment: та это черная магия... нет смысла ее загружать, xml в руки и вперед

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А на счет splash screen спасибо ! Хорошая идея для первого окна запуска